# What do the slightly different paths to npm install libraries mean?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I've seen two different ways to `npm install` libraries.  For example, looking at React Testing Library:

[Testing-library.com](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro)

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react
```

[CSS Tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/getting-started-with-react-testing-library/)

```
npm install --save-dev react-testing-library
```

I'm confused as to the difference — if any — between the two paths?

**EDIT**: I just found an [issue regarding this specific library](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/260):

> react-testing-library has moved to @testing-library/react. Please
>   uninstall react-testing-library and install @testing-library/react
>   instead, or use an older version of react-testing-library. Learn more
>   about this change here:
>   https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/260
>   Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command is an example of installing a scoped package. Here, `@testing-library` is a scope which contains the package `react`. Using a scope is optional and if not used (like in the second command) it'll fetch it from the default scope which is mostly github.

For more details you can read about `npm-scope` here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope